# Get all substring frequency ignoring space

Tags: python, string

I have some sets of string that I want to extract all the substring and its frequency that has more than 1 char

```
example_string = "coco crunch is nice nicenice"
```

this should return:

```
string count 

co -> 2

nice -> 3

nicenice -> 1

crunch -> 1

is -> 1
```

It is kind of brute-forcing the substrings.

references are welcomed. thanks.

Comment: Why is `coco` not counted in the desired output? If substrings are defined as two or more chars, should `ice` be another substring?

Comment: How come there isn't `cru`? and `nch`

Answer (score 1):

Try using this dictionary comprehension:

```
print({(k[:len(k)//2] if k.count(k[:len(k)//2]) > 1 and len(k[:len(k)//2]) > 1 else k): (example_string.count(k[:len(k)//2]) if k.count(k[:len(k)//2]) > 1 and len(k[:len(k)//2]) > 1 else example_string.count(k)) for k in example_string.split()})
```

Output:

```
{'co': 2, 'crunch': 1, 'is': 1, 'nice': 3}
```

If you want to also contain the original sub-strings:

```
from collections import Counter
print({**Counter(example_string.split()), **{(k[:len(k)//2] if k.count(k[:len(k)//2]) > 1 and len(k[:len(k)//2]) > 1 else k): (example_string.count(k[:len(k)//2]) if k.count(k[:len(k)//2]) > 1 and len(k[:len(k)//2]) > 1 else example_string.count(k)) for k in example_string.split()}})
```

Output:

```
{'coco': 1, 'crunch': 1, 'is': 1, 'nice': 3, 'nicenice': 1, 'co': 2}
```

Comment: Sorry not well verse with python, how can insert the result into the a dictionary